# Add a form to a MDI child

Tags: c#, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

In `Form1` I'm enabling `IsMdiContainer` and I added a `MenuStrip`. In `Form1_Load` I "new" `Form2` and I'm assiging `Form2.MdiParent` to `this` which is `Form1`. I'm also maximizing `Form2` and this operation works well.

In `Form2` I have a `treeView` on the left side of the form and on the right side of the form I would like to display a number of different forms with various editing capabilities which will be dependent upon the node or level selected in the `treeView`.

I would like to create a number of different forms for editing data that would be displayed in `Form2` depending on the selection from the `treeView`. I can't seem to add a form to the MdiChild and I've been seeing some posts where adding a form to a form may create some programming problems which I'm not sure about.

I really don't have any code to paste into this post because nothing seemed to work except for the Mdi Parent and Child relationship which was pretty simple.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It's much better to include the code then explain it !

Comment: Creating an MDI inside an MDI isn't going to work so well.  Put the TreeView on the MDI parent instead, dock it on the left.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of information on this subject, but some documentation can be difficult to understand for some new developers.  Follow these steps:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Create a Windows Form Application
3. Click your *Form*
4. Go to *Properties* for that *Form*
5. Minimum Size : 1366 pixels by 768 pixels.
6. Launch Maximized
7. The important element is **IsMdiContainer**
8. Open your Toolbox.
9. Go to *Menus*
10. Drag *FileMenu* onto your *Form*
11. Build your *Menu*
12. Then go to *Solution Explorer*
13. Right-Click *Add Item*
14. Add another *Form*
15. I left mine as *Form2* (In a real program, not a good name).

So within those fifteen steps, we have all that we need to accomplish our goal.  So what we will do to finish our task is:

1. Go back to our **First Form**
2. Go to our *FileMenu*
3. Double Click on the menu button you wish to link.

It will load a code view, inside the area put this:

```
Form2 newFrm = new Form2();
newFrm.MdiParent = this;
newFrm.Show();
```

What this code is doing is three distinct things:

- Line 1: It is actually calling our object, in this case a second form.  It is actually building our object for us.
- Line 2: Is actually linking our second form to our current form, this is physically turning our second form into a *Child Form*.
- Line 3: This is actually physically showing our second form when the button is clicked.

That is all you need to physically show a *Form*.

In regards to your second question, I'm not entirely sure what your attempting to accomplish.  It sounds like your trying to have a tree, then as a *Node* is selected the right hand side of the *Form* changes to specific context.

Now this isn't the nicest example, but do you mean something like this?

```
TreeNode node = treeView1.SelectedNode;
        if (node.Text.Contains("XP"))
        {                
            TextBox one = new TextBox();
            Panel i = new Panel();
            i.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
            i.BackColor = Color.Black;
            i.Controls.Add(one);
            i.Show();
            TreeFrm.ActiveForm.Controls.Add(i);               

        }
```

Not sure if that is what you are seeking. Obviously you'd want to implement a **FlowLayoutPanel** to make the positioning not a pain for you.  **Keep in mind an MDI Parent, with a Child Form acting as a MDI Parent will not work very well.  As most things will default to MDI Parent Forms Docking / Positioning.** This example is not pretty, but I'm not entirely sure of what your asking.

Are you trying to dock other forms or components on the same form?

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I have a treeView containing 4 different levels I would like to display 4 different editing screens preferrably as forms to the right of the treeView. I was accomplishing this with a tabControl. If level 2 was selected on my treeView, the 2nd tab in the tabControl was displayed. The problem with this solution is that I had to prevent the user from selecting a tab and that undermines how a user views a tab control. Instead I would like to display 4 forms and bring the appropriate form to the front based on the level selected in the treeView.

Comment: @Michael The sub area of code I wrote would apply, you'll want to use a `FlowLayoutPanel` but you may have to write the entire application on a single `Form` without a `MdiChild`.  As the process for docking to it will not truly occur, it will dock to the parent.  It is possible, but it will take a lot of trial and error.  Just docking a component through code to a child form can be a quest on it's own.  Hope that helps though.  If I have a few more ideas I'll post for you.