# visual c# code to load the Form1 again

Tags: c#, winforms, overriding, overloading, form-load

In my Visual C# program I have 2 forms call `Form1` & `Form2`.

`Form1` has a button call `btnfrm1` and `Form2` has a button call `btnfrm2`.

What I need my program to do is :-

When I press the `btnfrm1` it need to open `Form2` and hide the `Form1` & when I press the `btnfrm2` it needs to show the `Form1` again and close the `Form2`.

What I have coded for the `btnfrm1`'s click event is this

```
Form2 frm2= new Form2();
frm2.Show();
this.Hide();
```

But I don't know what to write in `Form2's btnfrm2` click event to make Form2 disappear and Form1 reappear.

Can someone help me?
any help I appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code

```
Form1 frm1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
frm1.Show();
this.Close();
```

Comment: Thank You so much @Masoud your code worked for me.The code is really simple.Thank you once again for helping me & I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to actually look into `MdiParent`, this will create a parent application.  All of the children forms will then appear within the parent.  So in your initial `form` you do the following:

- `MdiContainer` should be set to `true`.

It will be coupled with a `MenuStrip`, to work like a traditional application:

```
Child form = new Child();
form.Parent = this;
form.ShowDialog();
```

That way you can do this.  If you do your approach, you should use `Close` rather than `Hide` that way it automaticaly `Close` and allow you to reopen.  You could go to this answer, which I really went into alot of [detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575052/add-a-form-to-a-mdi-child/16575889#16575889), just ignore the second part about the *Tree View*.

Comment: Thank you Greg your code even work, but it is somewhat different from the one I expected. But thank you for your help and I appreciate your help too.

Answer (score 1):

Your secondary Form will need to know about your primary Form.

```
public class Form1
{
    private Form2 _form2;

    public void ShowForm2()
    {
        if(_form2 == null)
        {
            _form2 = new Form2();
            _form2.Bind(this);
        }
        this.Hide();
        _form2.Show();
    }
}

public class Form2
{
    private Form1 _form1;

    public void Bind(Form1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
    }

    public void ShowForm1()
    {
        this.Hide();
        _form1.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Silas Reinagel I tried your code, but in Form2.cs it underline the "Bind" word and shows a error of "Method must have a return type".I don't know what to return.But I think you may have some idea.

Comment: Thank you Silas Reinagel, now your code even work.Thank you for your help & I appreciate your help.