# Bring to Front MDI Child in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mdichild, mdiparent

I am new in using C# and its IDE, Visual Studio. I am now creating an internal frame embedded in a winform. I used MDI Child, setting my winform as MDI parent. The problem is that, whenever I run my MDI child inside the MDI client together with other components (panel, buttons, field, etc.), my MDI child appears behind those other components. Is there any way to bring my MDI child in front of all those components? If there is, please also help me how to set the MDI child location as it appears inside my winform. Your help will be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: The short answer, yes.  But what have you tried?

Comment: I tried using the code
MyForm mf = new MyForm();
mf.BringToFront();

but that didn't work

Comment: Still not entirely sure what your attempting, but I believe my first part of this answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575052/add-a-form-to-a-mdi-child/16575889#16575889 is what your attempting to do with Parent / Child Forms.

Comment: MDI child windows are parented to the MDI client window, the dark grey one.  Anything you put on top of it will always overlap the client windows.  Nothing you can do to fix that.  The only practical way to put any controls on the parent is by docking them to an edge, you'd use a Panel.  That shrinks the MDI client to the remaining space.